# Where is Assert defined in C# .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, assert, assertions

I have found tons of material how to use it, but not what
using XXX.YYY.ZZZ; directive should I use. Not even on the MSDN pages...

I keep getting error:

> "The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context"

So what package should I declare I am using ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182530.aspx

Comment: it is defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert(v=vs.90).aspx  "System.Diagnostics" Debug.Assert(bool condition,string message)

Comment: What type of material are you looking at? For example, do you mean NUnit's `Assert`? or MSTest's `Assert`? or do you mean the inbuilt `Debug.Assert`? or ...?

Comment: @Marc I'd like to use in first step simple Assert like in C Assert(a !=b), or the C# style using Assert class, Assert.IsEqual() ...
Later may be even test method, unit test...

Comment: `Assert.IsEqual` sounds like NUnit or MSTest - in which case: you'll find it in whichever test library you are targeting; test frameworks are *not* standard runtime asserts, though. For your "like in C" example: `Debug.Assert(a != b)`. Job done. Note this needs either `using System.Diagnostics;` directive, or fully qualified `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seems to be a lot of confusion over which `Assert` to use, and how, here's a fully working example (should compile fine, etc), using your C example from the comments of `Assert(a !=b)`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a = 5, b = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        Debug.Assert(a != b); // should get past this
        Console.WriteLine("world");
        b = 5;
        Debug.Assert(a != b); // should fail in debug mode
    }
}
```

Note this uses regular runtime assertions, not any particular / arbitrary test framework. Note that because `Debug.Assert` is a `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` method, it won't be invoked for release builds.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for Asserts in code, not unit tests:

[System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Getting error: Error 7 The type name 'Assert' does not exist in the type 'System.Diagnostics.Debug'

Comment: @Peter correct; `Assert` (in the context of `Debug.Assert`) is a method name, not a type. Again: what "material" have you been looking at, so that we can answer in the context of what you are looking at?